# how to change data type range in liferay

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-7, liferay-ide, liferay-7.1, liferay-7.2

In tables.sql file liferay created image table create script

```
create table Product_Image (
    uuid_ VARCHAR(75) null,
    id_ LONG not null primary key,
    view VARCHAR(75) null,
    imageUrl VARCHAR(75) null,
    productId LONG,
    createDate DATE null,
    modifiedDate DATE null
);
```

but passed imageUrl data is too long, Getting `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'imageUrl' at row 1`.
I tried to store data by changing `varchar(225)` that is worked but whenever run `builService` command automatically resets to `varchar(75)`. I tried with `ALTER TABLE Product_Image MODIFY COLUMN imageUrl VARCHAR(225);` in tables.sql file also modified data range in `indexes.sql` file there also resetting to original value. Added statements in `portal-ext.properties` like `jdbc.default.create.tables=false` `jdbc.default.update.database=false` and `build.auto.upgrade=false` still same thing happening.